# Detecting the visible fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement the `onbackpressed()` in android and my code is as follows

```
public void backpressed(){
    NDListeningFragment fragment1=(NDListeningFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ConnectedDevicesFragment.TAG);
          if(fragment1!=null && fragment1.isVisible())
          {
              super.onBackPressed();
          }
          else
          {
              fragment1=(NDListeningFragment)SimpleFragmentFactory.createFragment(ConnectedDevicesFragment.TAG);
              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,fragment1).commit();
              fragment1.setUserVisibleHint(true);

          }
}
```

The above code checks if the visible fragment is `ConnectedDevicesFragment`. If yes then `super()` is called and if not then I create `ConnectedDevicesFragment` and replace it in the framelayout.

But I am not able to implement in this way. When I press back button it reloads the `Connected DevicesFragment` again and again.

can you help with some workaround. 
Cheers!

Comment: you need to override the onBackPressed() in activity

Comment: Please see my edit. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You creates fragment1 object every time in the onBackPressed function it means it will not null and it is on invisible state. You need to add NDListeningFragment in backstack when you open NDListeningFragment first and check Is the fragment available in back stack. If yes then call super.onBackpressed.